# In SharePoint 2010 how to add target="_blank" for all <a> tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint-2010

I've a requirement to add a `target attribute` on `<a>` tag in Sharepoint2010. As by default there is no any option to select `target attribute` while making a Listing page.

I am using SharePoint Designer 2010 to make changes on pages.  I tried to add a `jquery CDN library` and a specific code on one page.  But after saving the page all code disappear .

> I need to know in Sharepoint where can I add this script so all the `<a>`
>   tag  added a `target="_blank"`.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
$('a[href]').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Have a look at reference screenshot.[image]

Comment: Add it in master page, just before the </body> tag

Answer (score 1):

Add your JavaScript in a text file and save it in style library and using content editor webpart refer the file.

Are you trying to open all the links in a new tab or new window ? If yes then adding target attribute to the anchor tab will not help. By default List view have target attribute as "_self". Listview title column has onclick event also associated. Use below JavaScript to solve your issue:

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
                        function EditLink2(current, id)
                        {
                            var win = window.open(current.href, '_blank');
                            win.focus();
                        }  

            </script>
```

Comment: your solution somewhere really helpful for me. but the code you provided really didn't worked for me; May we your code work in any other situation. But in my case it doesn't solved. But by following your instructions `+` using some jquery code my problem were solved as. Thanks for your support. giving you `+1`.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your master page, just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

   $('a').attr('target', '_blank');

});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but doesn't solve my issue. Anyways thanks for your support.